# Parsing json file content in java

Tags: java, json

I have a json file which contains below json data.

```
[{"id":1025,
"key":"SVS",
"prj_name":"SVS",
"prj_scope":"PR8",
"prj_qualifier":"WW",
"date":"2016-03-29T06:00:26-0400",
"creationDate":"2013-04-12T09:03:35-0400",
"prj_lname":"SVS",
"csr":[{"key":"test_success","test_output":85.3,"org_val":"78.3%"}]}]
```

I want to read test_output value in java. I tried with few json-simple api. Below is the code which I wrote.

```
StringBuffer sbf = new StringBuffer();
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("C:/Users/java_backups/Downloads/output.json");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
String line="";
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sbf.append(line);
}
System.out.println(sbf.toString());
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray jsonArray= (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(sbf.toString());
```

size of jsonArray is one only. I do not have any clue how can I read test_output value from json string.

Comment: I haven't used JSON with java so I don't know this for sure, but my guess is your array only has 1 element in it because you're only parsing one JSON object. And since it's an object, you should be able to access its properties with jsonArray[0].id, etc.

Comment: jsonArray[0] will return me complete string and I do not see any way to access elements by their name.

Comment: Looking at the documentation for JSONParser, I'm not convinced you're actually parsing the file correctly; which package are you using? javax.json.stream? Or an external package from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jackson for simplicity:

```
public class Test {

    private static final String JSON = "[{\"id\":1025,\"key\":\"SVS\",\"prj_name\":\"SVS\",\"prj_scope\":\"PR8\",\"prj_qualifier\":\"WW\",\"date\":\"2016-03-29T06:00:26-0400\",\"creationDate\":\"2013-04-12T09:03:35-0400\",\"prj_lname\":\"SVS\",\"csr\":[{\"key\":\"test_success\",\"test_output\":85.3,\"org_val\":\"78.3%\"}]}]";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(JSON);
        System.out.println(actualObj.findValue("test_output"));
    }

}
```

Dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you only have 1 output with the given name in each JsonObject, this will do the trick. Just iterate over the JsonArray and find the value for each JsonObject. In case your array is always just 1 element, just ignore the iteration part and simply use it as I did above.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. The only thing I want to add, Object Mapper class is available in jackson-all package, if any one not using maven.